# If I create an array of the parental class, how do I access a method from the sub class through the array object?

Tags: java, class, oop, methods, super

I have a program I am working with to help me practice my coding skills. The program has the following scenario: there is a classroom of 20 students, where the record is taken of the students' names, surnames, and age. Half of these students take part in the school's athletics. Here, record is kept of their races that they have done and the ones they've won. 
In this program, I have three classes:

1. runStudents - class with main method
2. Students (String name, String surname, int age) - parental class
3. AthleticStudents (String name, String surname, int age, int races, int victories) - sub class

The user should be able to add another race (and win) to the object. As seen by the code provided, an Array is created to store the 20 Students objects. I have to be able to access a method to alter the object in the array, but this method is not in the parental class (the class the objects are created from.

```
public class Students
{
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private int age;

    public Students()
    {   
    }

    public Students(String name, String surname, int age)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getSurname()
    {
        return this.surname;
    }

    public double getAge()
    {
        return this.age;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname)
    {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public void setAge(int age)
    {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format("name\t\t: %s\nsurname\t\t: %s\nage\t\t: %s", 
        this.name, this.surname, this.age);
    }
}

public class AthleticStudents extends Students
{
    private int races;
    private int victories;

    public AthleticStudents()
    {

    }

    public AthleticStudents(String name, String surname, int age, int 
        races, int victories)
    {
        super(name, surname, age);
        this.races = races;
        this.victories = victories;
    }

    public int getRaces()
    {
        return this.races;
    }

    public int getVictories()
    {
        return this.victories;
    }

    public void setRaces(int races)
    {
        this.races = races;
    }

    public void setVictories(int victories)
    {
        this.victories = victories;
    }    

    public void anotherRace()
    {
        this.races = this.races + 1;
    }   

    public void anotherWin()
    {
        this.victories = this.victories + 1;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return super.toString() + String.format("\nnumber of races\t: 
        %s\nnumber of wins\t: %s", this.races, this.victories);
    }
}

public class runStudents
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Students[] myStudents = new Students[20];

        myStudents[0] = new Students("John", "Richards", 15);
        myStudents[1] = new AthleticStudents("Eva", "Grey", 14, 3, 1);
        myStudents[2] = new Students("Lena", "Brie", 15);


        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            System.out.println(myStudents[i].toString() + "\n\n");
    }
}
```

I want to be able to do the following:

`AthleticStudents[1].anotherRace();`

but cannot do so as the array object is derived from the parental class, and I declared the method in the sub class. How can I link the two?

Comment: A class name should be in singular form and be written in PascalCase.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you create an array of the parent class instances. Just cast the instance this way (you better check whether the element is the instance of a subclass):

```
if (AthleticStudents[1] instanceof AthleticStudents) 
   ((AthleticStudents) AthleticStudents[1]).anotherRace();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will take it into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for but it worked well for me. Instead of trying to access AthleticStudents method anotherRace() like that, try this in your main method.

```java
Students[] myStudents = new Students[20];

        myStudents[0] = new Students("John", "Richards", 15);
        myStudents[1] = new AthleticStudents("Eva", "Grey", 14, 3, 1);
        myStudents[2] = new Students("Lena", "Brie", 15);

        AthleticStudents addRace= (AthleticStudents)myStudents[1];
        addRace.anotherRace(); //This will increment Eva's race count to 4

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            System.out.println(myStudents[i].toString() + "\n\n");
```

All I did was cast the element into an object AthleticStudents named 'addRace'.  By casting myStudents[1] to this new object you are able to access all of AthleticStudents methods.

I just saw the other answer posted which works just as well!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure that i understand your question, because you are a bit inconsistent with your capitalization. runStudents is a class, while AthleticStudents is both a class and an array. But i’ll try.

IF i did understand your question, you have an array `Student[] studentArray`. Some `Student` objects in `studentArray` are `AthleticStudent`s, others are not. You have a specific `AthleticStudent eva` which is in `studentArray[]` having let’s say index 1, and you want to add to her `anotherRace()`. Your call `studentArray[1].anotherRace` does not compile because the compiler treats that element as a `Student` and not as a `AthleticStudent`.

The trick is to cast the element to `AthleticStudent`. I omit the test of the element of being really an `AthleticStudent`; you will have to do that test in your code.

```
((AthleticStudent) studentArray[1]).anotherRace();
```

Comment: I apologise for the confusion. I've only started studying programming now and I'm still getting used to the capitalisation rules in Java, as I've only worked with Delphi before. I will try to pay more attention to it next time. The way you explained it made perfect sense, my code now works. Thank you so so much!